# Is a positive sequences of real numbers that converge to zero eventually decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I wonder if a sequence of real numbers that converges to zero, where every term is positive is eventually decreasing. Is this true ? I have an idea on how to prove it by contradiction. If this isn’t true, we can always find a term in the sequence bigger than any term before it. We choose a subsequence of these “peaks”, and show it converges to something greater than zero, which is a contradiction. Is this a valid proof ?

Comment: "*bigger than any term before it*" $\;-\;$ No, just bigger than the previous term.

Comment: Yes thank you, that’s what I meant

Answer (score 7):

Consider the sequence
$$x_n = \frac{2+(-1)^n}{2^n}$$
This alternates between larger and smaller values, so it never becomes decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$a_n={\sin^2(n) \over n}$$

[$\hspace{3cm}$[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkoC9.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can take the sequence $a_1 = 1, a_2 = \dfrac{1}{2}, a_3 = \dfrac{3}{4}, a_4 = \dfrac{1}{4}, a_5 = \dfrac{3}{8}, ...$. You can see the pattern yourself and the sequence does converge to $0$ while having the property that: $a_1 >a_2 < a_3 > a_4 < a_5....$

Answer (score 0):

Here are many counterexamples.

Start with any positive sequence $(a_n)$ that converges to zero.

Now define a new sequence:
$$b_n = \begin{cases}
a_k &\quad\text{if $n=2k-1$ is odd} \\
2a_k &\quad\text{if $n=2k$ is even}
\end{cases}
$$
Every even term of the sequence $(b_n)$ will be greater than the preceding odd term so $(b_n)$ is certainly not decreasing, in fact it is not even "eventually decreasing". But $(b_n)$ is a positive sequence converging to zero.